# How do I grab an array list from firebase and update the values in it? Why are my values not updated?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The isRoomLiked boolean value does not get updated in firebase when I tried to update it. The like button text cannot be changed to unliked when I liked it for some of the rooms. For the rooms that could be liked, they cannot be unliked. When I exit the liked page, the liked button should be showing "Unlike" as I have liked the room, but it jumps back to like.

```
    private void readFavDB(FavListCallback callback){
    userDocFav.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                List<Map<String, Object>> favRoomListData = (List<Map<String, Object>>) documentSnapshot.get("favRoomList");
                ArrayList<Room> favRoomList = new ArrayList<>();

                // Loop through the list of Room objects and convert them to Room instances
                for (Map<String, Object> roomData : favRoomListData) {
                    long roomIDLong = (long) roomData.get("roomID");
                    int roomID = (int) roomIDLong;
                    boolean isRoomLikedRead = (boolean) roomData.get("isRoomLiked");
                    Room retrievedRoom = new Room(roomID, null, null, null, 0, null, 0, null, true, 0, isRoomLikedRead);
                    favRoomList.add(retrievedRoom);
                    Log.v(title, "In the loop:"+ favRoomList);
                }
                // Call the callback method with the favorite list
                callback.onFavListLoaded(favRoomList);
            } else {
                //No doc
                Log.d("Firebase", "Document not found.");
            }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.e("Firebase", "Error fetching document: " + e);
        }
    });
    Log.v(title, "After List"+favRoomList);
}

    public interface FavListCallback {
    void onFavListLoaded(ArrayList<Room> favRoomList);
}

 private void updateLikedStatusDB(int roomID, boolean updateLikedStatus){
    String fieldToMatch = "roomID";
    //String roomIDString = Integer.toString(roomID);
    // Create a query to find the document that matches the specified condition
    Query query = db.collection("favRoomList")
            .whereEqualTo(fieldToMatch, roomID);

    // Execute the query and get the result
    query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener< QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    // Get the document ID of the matched document
                    String documentId = document.getId();

                    // Create a map with the field you want to update and its new value
                    Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<>();
                    updates.put("isRoomLiked", updateLikedStatus);

                    // Update the field in the matched document
                    db.collection("favRoomList").document(userDocID)
                            .update(updates)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    // Update successful
                                    Log.d("Firebase", "Field updated successfully!");
                                }
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    // Update failed
                                    Log.e("Firebase", "Error updating field: " + e);
                                }
                            });
                }
            } else {
                // Query failed
                Log.e("Firebase", "Error getting documents: " + task.getException());
            }
        }
    });


}
        Button likedButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Get the serialized array string from SharedPreferences
    String serializedArray = sharedPreferences.getString("favouriteList", "");

    // Convert the serialized string back to an ArrayList using the delimiter
    String[] arrayElements = serializedArray.split(",");
    ArrayList<String> storedFavList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arrayElements));

    likedButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            readFavDB(new FavListCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onFavListLoaded(ArrayList<Room> favRoomList) {
                    boolean isRoomFound = false;
                    List<Room> roomsToRemove = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (Room room : favRoomList) {
                        if (room.getRoomID() == roomReceived.getRoomID()) {
                            isRoomFound = true;
                            boolean isRoomLiked = room.isRoomLiked();
                            Log.v(title, "Is Room Liked when Retrieving:" + isRoomLiked);
                            isRoomLiked = !isRoomLiked;
                            //updating the value of isRoomLiked to the opposite, this does not update the database
                            room.setRoomLiked(isRoomLiked);
                            //updating the boolean value in the firebase base
                            updateLikedStatusDB(room.getRoomID(),isRoomLiked);
                            Log.v(title, "RoomID After Retrieving:" + room.getRoomID());
                            Log.v(title, "Is Room Liked After setting it to opposite:" + isRoomLiked);

                            if (isRoomLiked) {
                                likedButton.setText("Unlike");
                            } else {
                                likedButton.setText("Like");
                                roomsToRemove.add(room);
                                Log.v(title, "These are the rooms to remove"+roomsToRemove.add(room));
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    // If the roomReceived was not found in favRoomList, add or remove it accordingly.
                    if (!isRoomFound) {
                        if (roomReceived.isRoomLiked()) {
                            likedButton.setText("Unlike");
                            favRoomList.add(roomReceived);
                        } else {
                            likedButton.setText("Like");
                            // If the room is not liked, remove it from the list (if it exists)
                            favRoomList.removeIf(room -> room.getRoomID() == roomReceived.getRoomID());
                        }
                    }

                    // Remove the rooms that need to be removed
                    favRoomList.removeAll(roomsToRemove);

                    // Update the database after all modifications are completed
                    favouritetoDB(favRoomList);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I am expecting a like and unlike toggle button based on the boolean of the room that I grab from Firebase. It is an array.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Besides that, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-realtime-database-to-a-list-of-objects-53f27b33c8f3) might help.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).